# How do I write a Django ORM query where the select table shares a common column with another table?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, join, orm

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have these two models.  Note they both have a similar field

```
class Article(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)


class WebPageStat(models.Model):
    objects = WebPageStatManager()
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    score = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

I would like to write a Django ORM query that selects one of the models but does a join on the shared column in order to do a comparison on the "score" field.  I tried the below, but alas the error

```
Article.objects.filter(publisher=webpagestat.publisher, webpagestat.score__gte==100)
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

How do I include the "WebPageStat" table in my join?

Comment: Have you taken a look to `select_related`?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is easily done in Django by using [lookups that span relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). In your example you need to add a way of referencing the related objects in the ORM. This is donde by setting the `related_name` attribute of the `ForeignKey` fields. Although this is not strictly necessary it is more clear in this way. You can read more about [`related_name` and `related_query_name` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). In short, your models should look like:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')


class WebPageStat(models.Model):
    objects = WebPageStatManager()
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stats')
    score = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Once this is done your query will be carried out by the following code:

```
Article.objects.filter(publisher__stats__score__gte=100)
```

What this query is doing in short is selecting every article whose publisher has at least one web page stat whose score is greater than or equal to 100.